# Toolbar/Nav drawer not working with tabbed view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I'm having an issue getting my toolbar and navigation drawer to show on a new layout file. It's working for the whole app, except the new tabbed layout view.

I try to activate it in the onCreate of the new java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);

    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
```

I no longer get an error, but the toolbar still doesn't show up. I'm wondering if it's something wrong with my layout file.

baseactivity:

```
public static final int HOME = 1;
public static final int MY_WORKOUT = 2;
public static final int MAXES = 3;
public static final int PROGRESS = 4;
public static final int WORKOUTS = 5;
public static final int HELP = 6;

private Class mNextActivity;

public static String mTitle = AppConstant.SHIEKO_WORKOUT;

public static int mType = HOME;

protected Toolbar mToolBar;

private NavigationDrawerFragment mDrawerFragment;

protected Toolbar activateToolbar() {
    if(mToolBar == null) {
        mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        switch (mType) {
            case HOME:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.SHIEKO_WORKOUT);
                break;
            case MY_WORKOUT:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.MY_WORKOUT);
                break;
            case MAXES:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.SET_MY_MAXES);
                break;
            case PROGRESS:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.MY_PROGRESS);
                break;
            case WORKOUTS:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.WORKOUTS);
                break;
            case HELP:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.FEEDBACK);
        }
    }
    return mToolBar;
}
```

Here is my activity: I also have 3 other fragment xml pages that are for the 3 tabs, those do not include the toolbar or nav bar as it's my understanding they are below the tabview.. correct me if I'm wrong please..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
             layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

    <fragment
        android:name="com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.app_bar)` has returned null. Please check that exists in your XML layout

Comment: It was in there, but I moved it to a different spot. Now I'm not getting an error, and the tab view is below where the toolbar should be, but it's still not showing up :(

Comment: Can you [edit] with a [mcve], please? It's hard to tell how these two snippets of code interact

Comment: I'm pretty new to android, and was unable to make a minimal, complete, verifiable example unfortunately, but I updated the the main post with my xml layout code. I have 3 other fragment layouts that only contain FrameLayout and Textview, but I don't think they would need the <include toolbar and appbar as if im right they are below the tabview

Comment: That is the workout days XML?

Comment: Yes correct, then I have fragment_workout_days, fragment_sub_page1, fragment_sub_page2.. just noticed I have 2 java files, subPage1 and subPage2, in a layout file.. do I have to add the toolbars and navdrawer to them too? I wouldn't think so..

Comment: Again, hard to tell since you don't have a minimal example. Try to get a Toolbar on one Activity working. Once you get that, add some tabs. Then, add just one Fragment... Etc.

Comment: I ended up getting the toolbar to work by moving the <include appbar and toolbar /> code into the AppBarLayout.. But now for some reason my textbxes arent showing up when I change tabs LOL.. if it's not one thing it's another.. I'm thinking it must be something wrong with my layout file, which I updated in the first post.. ts almost like one of the things height values is set to match parent, as the background colour is taking up the whole screen now.

Comment: Got it to work! Yay! I had to move the <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  Starting tag
to after the AppBarLayout closing tag!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ViewPager>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- Slider Menu -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Btw no need to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(AppConstant.WORKOUTS)`, you can just call `setTitle()` to set the title of actionBar.

Comment: My BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity, then my new class extends BaseActivity.. Thanks for the tip about setting the title!

Comment: Updated the new code for xml layout, please let me know if you need anything else. There is 3 tab layout fragments for each tab, but they only contain a frame layout and textview